# Programmable Controller for Sensorless BLDC Motor

Tags: motor, control, brushless-dc-motor

I'm trying to find a programmable controller (or system for controlling) a sensorless BLDC motor - 24V, 20A. I want to control speed, fwd/rev, and dwell time in certain positions.  Apologies if this is really obvious, I'm a chemist but not an EE so any pointers grately appreciated!

For context this is a battery operated scissor that would normally be operated by pressing or depressing the handle.  I've stripped out the battery and previous controllers and have connected it to a power supply with a cheap BLDC and a timed relay to change direction.  This kind of works but I need more accurate control.

Comment: Welcome to EE! Sorry, it sounds as you ask for recommendation what to acquire, which EE is not about. If you can formulate this into a question, that is about a design of yours, or ciruitry, then EE users is happy to answer.

Comment: If you ask at a manufacturers forum, e.g. the Texas Instruments [Motor drivers forum](https://e2e.ti.com/support/motor-drivers-group/motor-drivers/f/motor-drivers-forum), they might be able to recommend a controller which matches your requirements.

Comment: Okay thank you.  Didn't know about the other forum, I will try there.